# Reading - and effect - of (default) tikz/pgf keys?

Tags: tikz-pgf, key-value

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass[varwidth,tightpage,border=1bp]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\pagecolor{yellow!15} % ignored with preview, but not w/ varwidth

\begin{document}

  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \tikzset{/tikz/line width=1cm} % no effect
    \draw %[/tikz/line width=1cm] % has effect here
      (0,0) -- ++(1,0)
      node[fill,scale=0.5](A){};

    \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/line width}{\tmp}
    \typeout{tmpX \tmp \meaning\tmp}

  \end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

My first question is: here I'm trying to `\tikzset{/tikz/line width=1cm}`, but it has no effect (only on document size); the output is:

[image: test03a.png]

If I use the `\draw[/tikz/line width=1cm]`, then there *is* effect, and the output is:

[image: test03b.png]

So, the question is - how come `/tikz/line width` doesn't have any effect? I would have thought it is a "master" key/variable of sorts (which kicks in, if nothing else is specified).

But even more important for me is - how do I read `tikz`/`pgf` keys? As you can see, I'm trying with `\pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/line width}{\tmp}`, but when I try to print it to stdout, I get this:

```
tmpX \tmp \relax
```

... which means that `\tmp` in unexpandable, probably because it has been "let" to `\relax`; and so I cannot read any information in `/tikz/line width`.

So, how can I read TikZ/PGF keys - in an expandable format, so I can use them in code?

---

EDIT: After reading [Simple example of pgfkeys](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/114012/simple-example-of-pgfkeys), I simply tried `.initial`:

```
\tikzset{/tikz/line width/.initial=1cm}
```

... and afterwards, the stdout printout is:

```
tmpX 1cmmacro:->1cm
```

... which means my syntax for reading keys was correct - but apparently, the key `/tikz/line width` did *not* exist, even if I tried to "set" it?!

My question then becomes - what controls the line width of the `\draw` in the case when we do not specify anything, and how can I find and print the corresponding key values (if they exist)?

---

possibly related:

- [tikz pgf - Problems with pgfkeys - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/157323/problems-with-pgfkeys)
- [Re: Question about \tikzset, maybe related to \pgfkeys - gmane.comp.tex.pgf.user](http://article.gmane.org/gmane.comp.tex.pgf.user/3202)

Comment: `\tikzset{/tikz/<key>}` sets the key `/tikz/tikz/<key>` either use `\pgfkeys` or remove the `/tikz/`

Comment: Hah! Thanks, @percusse - had no idea the paths work in this way... Just tested it though, still have to use `\tikzset{line width/.initial=1cm}` to get an effect as described in the OP... Cheers!

Comment: `line width` doesn't hold a value. Instead it sets the length `\pgflinewidth`. You might want to read that dimen instead of reading a key because the dimen can change without changing the key value.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Not every key sets a value.

A key can execute arbitrary code.  If we look in `tikz.code.tex` then we see that when you invoke `\tikzset{line width=2pt}` then it doesn't set a value, it invokes `\tikz@semiaddlinewidth{2pt}`.  This, in turn, expands to `\tikz@addoption{\pgfsetlinewidth{2pt}}\pgfmathsetlength\pgflinewidth{2pt}`.

There are two things going on here.  One is that `\pgfsetlinewidth` is set up to be invoked at a later time.  The other is that `\pgflinewidth` is set to the desired width.  Now, `\pgfsetlinewidth` is the Real McCoy here.  It sets the line width down in the depths of PGF's subsystem.  All the messing around with `\pgflinewidth` doesn't actually set the real line width.  It needs a genuine call to `\pgfsetlinewidth` to do this.

But the key `/tikz/line width` does not directly call `\pgfsetlinewidth`.  It sets it up to be invoked at a later time.  This is what `\tikz@addoption` does.  These options get invoked once the path has been constructed and before it is rendered.  But the option list is blanked at the start of a path construction.  So the effect of the `\tikz@addoption` is nullified by the following `\draw` command before it has a chance to take effect.

You could do `\tikzset{every path/.append style={line width=\pgflinewidth}}` to ensure that the ambient line width is used as the default line width for every path.  Or you could define a new key, `\tikzset{ambient line width/.code={\pgfsetlinewidth{#1}}}` (no need to explicitly set `\pgflinewidth` here).

As Paul Gaborit noted in the comments, you can achieve a change of line width for a group of paths by putting them in a scope and setting the line width in the optional argument to the scope.  That is,

```
\begin{scope}[line width=1cm]
...
\end{scope}
```

sets the line width to 1cm for all the intervening paths.

The reason for this is that the optional arguments to the `scope` environment are passed to `\tikzset` and then immediately after, the token list `\tikz@options` is expanded.  This means that the part of the `line width` key that is hidden in the `\tikz@options` token list is actually executed and therefore the line width is set properly deep in the heart of PGF.

Comment: Many thanks for the answer, @LoopSpace - it explains why I got the results that I did... Cheers!

Comment: To fix the `line width` of multiple paths, you can use `line width` as a scope option...

Comment: @PaulGaborit I didn't know that!  Looking at the code, the important part is that `\begin{scope}[<stuff>]` includes `\tikzset{<stuff>}\tikz@options` so the `\tikz@addoption` part of the `line width=<length>` key does get executed when the scope starts, setting the line width properly.  I'll edit that into my answer as it's a useful work-around.

Comment: Why is this excellent explanation missing in the TikZ manual?  I've searched for hours...